# Table toggleclass jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this example I have this onclick method where I want to change the row from plus to minus. I also want all the other ones to go back to the default plus. is there anyway to do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  collapsed();

});
var collapsed = function(e, counter) {
  $("#data  tr").each(function() {
    console.log('Data')
  });
};
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="btn tooltips btn-green" id="maincounter_1" data-maincounter="1" data-container="body" data-placement="top" onclick="collapsed(this,1)"><i id="icon_1" class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
  </tr>
  <td>
    <span class="btn tooltips btn-green" id="maincounter_2" data-maincounter="2" data-container="body" data-placement="top" onclick="collapsed(this,2)"><i id="icon_1" class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
    </tr>
    <td>
      <span class="btn tooltips btn-green" id="maincounter_1" data-maincounter="1" data-container="body" data-placement="top" onclick="collapsed(this,3)"><i id="icon_1" class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
      </tr>
      <td>
        <span class="btn tooltips btn-green" id="maincounter_1" data-maincounter="1" data-container="body" data-placement="top" onclick="collapsed(this,4)"><i id="icon_1" class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
        </tr>
        <td>
          <span class="btn tooltips btn-green" id="maincounter_1" data-maincounter="1" data-container="body" data-placement="top" onclick="collapsed(this,5)"><i id="icon_1" class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
          </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you have duplicated `id` values, which is invalid HTML.  That could potentially hinder your JavaScript functionality.  Aside from that... What have you tried and what isn't working?  The `collapsed` function doesn't appear to use either of the parameters it's receiving.

Comment: How are you changing the icon? Your snippet doesn't appear to do anything apart from log to the console.

Comment: "*is there anyway to do this?*" - yes, there is, what happened when you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  You mention toggleClass(), did you try that?  "*I have this onclick method"* - please include this in the question so it becomes a "help-me" question rather than a "do it for me" demand.

Comment: If you format your code properly, you can see your html is invalid - you seem to be closing `tr` tags instead of `td`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might get you started:

```
function handle_row_click(e){
  const row = e.target.closest('tr');
  const fa = row.querySelector(':scope > td > span > i.fa');
  if (fa.classList.contains('fa-plus') ){
    fa.classList.remove('fa-plus');
    fa.classList.add('fa-minus');
  } else if (fa.classList.contains('fa-minus') ){
    fa.classList.remove('fa-minus');
    fa.classList.add('fa-plus');
  }
}
```

#### Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   collapsed();
   $('table#data').click(handle_row_click);        
        
 });
 var collapsed = function (e,counter) {
   $("#data  tr").each(function () {
      //console.log('Data')
   });
};
function handle_row_click(e){
  reset_all_to_plus(e);
  const row = e.target.closest('tr');
  const fa = row.querySelector(':scope > td > span > i.fa');
  if (fa.classList.contains('fa-plus') ){
    fa.classList.remove('fa-plus');
    fa.classList.add('fa-minus');
  } else if (fa.classList.contains('fa-minus') ){
    fa.classList.remove('fa-minus');
    fa.classList.add('fa-plus');
  }
}
function reset_all_to_plus(e){
   if ( !e.target.classList.contains('fa-minus') ){ // ADDED THIS TEST
     document.querySelectorAll('table#data tr').forEach(row => {
         const fa = row.querySelector(':scope > td > span > i.fa');
         fa.classList.remove('fa-minus');
         fa.classList.add('fa-plus');
     });
   }
}
```

```css
td{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data">
<tr><td>
<span class="btn tooltips btn-green" id="maincounter_1" data-maincounter="1" data-container="body" data-placement="top" ><i id="icon_1" class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<span class="btn tooltips btn-green" id="maincounter_2" data-maincounter="2" data-container="body" data-placement="top"><i id="icon_1" class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<span class="btn tooltips btn-green" id="maincounter_1" data-maincounter="1" data-container="body" data-placement="top"><i id="icon_1" class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<span class="btn tooltips btn-green" id="maincounter_1" data-maincounter="1" data-container="body" data-placement="top"><i id="icon_1" class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<span class="btn tooltips btn-green" id="maincounter_1" data-maincounter="1" data-container="body" data-placement="top"><i id="icon_1" class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: one thing is that when I use the fa-minus it will not go back to the fa-plus

Comment: Fixed. The `reset_all_to_plus()` function was switching all symbols back to pluses, so the "else if" test in `handle_row_click` never saw a minus. I added a test in the `reset_all_to_plus()` function to stop it from resetting the clicked-on row to `+` if it was currently a `-`, and that fixed it.